# How can I monitor which data an iOS transmits over WiFi?

Tags: networking, privacy, ios

I use a third party keyboard which has suggestions and the developer claims – on his website – that it stores everything locally on the device, but there is no word on this matter in app description on the App Store.

So I was wondering if there is a way I could monitor the data being sent/received by this app while connected to WiFi, as it seems there is no data being sent/received over cellular cause it doesn't appear in the "USE CELLULAR DATA FOR" in *Settings > Cellular*.

Comment: @DavidPostill I think it's fine for the question to stay here. The solution requires a dedicated computer acting as a man-in-the-middle proxy to which the iPhone connects. Or at least a router capable of sniffing WiFi data, if the data is sent without app-layer encryption.

Comment: @slhck Fair enough. VTC and comment removed.

Comment: What networking equipment (other computers, router, etc.) do you have at hand?

Comment: @slhck thanks for your help, I've got a MacBook Pro & a D-Link router.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Paros](http://www.parosproxy.org/index.shtml) for that. Take a look at this detailed guide for more information: http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2009/06/sniff-your-iphones-network-traffic/

The only problem with Paros is that it only captures HTTP GET/POST requests using the standard method, so to get all network traffic, do the following:

> 1. Just turn on network sharing over WiFi and run a packet sniffer like [Cocoa Packet Analyzer](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/index.php) (in OSX).
> 2. Then connect to the new network from iPhone over WiFi. (SystemPreferences->Sharing->InternetSharing)